# Render QtQuick GUI over SDL

Tags: qt, sdl, qt-quick

Trying to render QML user interface into the SDL window.

There is an SDL 1.2 game that creates an OpenGL context via `SDL_SetVideoMode` with `SDL_OPENGLBLIT` flag.

The idea is to get the OpenGL context handle and pass it to the QQuickRenderControl that will draw the GUI over the scene.

Getting the native context (example for X11):

```
GLXContext currentContext;
SDL_SysWMinfo wmInfo;
SDL_VERSION(&wmInfo.version);
if (SDL_GetWMInfo(&wmInfo))
{
    Display *display = wmInfo.info.x11.gfxdisplay;
    currentContext = glXGetCurrentContext();
    assert(currentContext);
}
```

Adopting it in Qt:

```
QOpenGLContext *ctx = new QOpenGLContext;
ctx->setNativeHandle(QVariant::fromValue<QGLXNativeContext>(
    QGLXNativeContext(currentContext, wmInfo.info.x11.display, wmInfo.info.x11.window)
));
```

And creating the QQuickRenderControl:

```
QQuickRenderControl *renderControl = new QQuickRenderControl;
renderControl->initialize(ctx);
```

But QQuickRenderControl can't start without QWindow:

```
QQuickRenderControl::initialize called with no associated window
```

Also `ctx->isValid()` and `ctx->makeCurrent()` return false.

How to make it work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At least it's possible with SDL2.

Qt application singleton must be running, window must be extracted from the native handle and passed to the RenderControl.

Comment: Could you please provide some more information? I get ctx->isValid() returning false even with SDL2

Comment: @MiguelElMerendero, a project that uses that: https://github.com/SFTtech/openage You can copy-paste the `libopenage/gui/guisys` directory into your project and look how integration is done in `libopenage/gui_basic.h` and `libopenage/gui_basic.cpp`. It works on Linux, the Mac part needs a Mac developer to fix it, if you really want Windows - I can publish a small patch to make it run on Windows. Btw, the minimal version of it (no error checking, lots of memory leaks and hardcode, Linux-only): https://github.com/ChipmunkV/openage/commit/c2eb84bbfc22119f04dd32ed860f987716edb6c8

Comment: Thanks, your example is useful! Unfortunately it's not working for me, I'm on windows and adapted some code, but I still can't get a valid context. I don't understand why, I've opened this issue here: http://forum.qt.io/topic/68383/qtquick-into-an-sdl2-window/4

Comment: @MiguelElMerendero, also there is an example in [QTBUG-50309](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-50309) (see zip files in the attachments).

Comment: Awesome, thank you. I ported the cmake project to a standalone project for QtCreator and attached it to your bugreport. At least your example showed me that this system works. Anyway, I still can't get a valid context in my project, I'm suspecting the problem is in the SDL side somewhere around [here](https://github.com/illogica/Qtesseract/blob/master/src/engine/main.cpp#L539), but I have to keep trying.

Comment: @MiguelElMerendero, you're getting a valid context in that small standalone example? (btw, be careful about that bug report. It's only about the keyboard input handling. You're seeing the same problem with the TextInput?)

Comment: Yes, I'm getting a valid context on the standalone example, and yes I updated your bug report because I experience the same bug and it's quite nasty implementing a GUI without being able to type in it. In this very moment I'm running some debug sessions between the standalone example and my project to see what's making the difference. Shall we have a quick talk in #qt irc or forum.qt.io chat?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115077/discussion-between-velkan-and-miguel-el-merendero).